# Texlive cannot find files in TEXMFHOME

Tags: biblatex, texlive, installing, texlive-2017, kpsewhich

Texlive doesn't detect any files found under TEXMFHOME, even though `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME` returns the correct path (`~/.texlive2017/texmf-var/`).

Running Texlive 2017 on Ubuntu, installed from the ppa ([ppa:jonathonf/texlive-2017](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/texlive-2017)).

Comment: Is there a biblatex style named `tufte-handout`? Not that I know. What file in `TEXMFHOME` is not found? What's its complete path?

Comment: I only know about `tufte-handout.cls`, which is definitely *not* a biblatex style. The message is quite clear: you want `\documentclass{tufte-handout}` instead.

Comment: Where *exactly*  did you place it in texmfhome?

Comment: @egreg, yes my bad. tufte-handout.bbx is an old citation style that I created. It's also under TEXMFHOME. The document style tufte-handout is found. I'll edit the question

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tried directly under TEXMFHOME or under a subfolder. Do I need to stick to a specific dir structure? I never had that problem in the past.

Comment: It should go under `<TEXMFHOME>/tex/latex/mystyles` (the name of the last directory can be chosen at will). On the other hand, the value returned for `TEXMFHOME` is wrong and should be `~/texmf/`

Comment: Thanks! Works now. I didn't know I had to stick to `<TEXMFHOME>tex/latex/` structure.

Comment: Do you think this is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/35864?

Comment: @moewe It is to some extent but the selected answer did not mention the strict structure that is required: `<TEXMFHOME>/tex/latex/local` and the fact that beyond `<TEXMFHOME>/tex/latex/l` naming isn't strict. The second answer by Joseph Wright mentions the strict but isn't the chosen answer

Comment: I think the 'Following the TeX directory structure, you should place your file in a subdirectory like `~/texmf/tex/latex/commonstuff/`' is quite clear. But OK.

Comment: @egreg Do you want to type up an answer here?

Comment: @moewe I read the answer you're referring to but the part about dir structure didn't strike me. Nevertheless, I wouldn't mind marking this question as a duplicate.

Comment: Let's wait if @egreg takes this. If not I will vote to close later...

Comment: @moewe voted to close